# Python: Getting None Type variables

Tags: python

I try to write a little script to sync(Mirroring) 2 directory apps, i have a config like this

```
app 1                app 2
Network_Devices      Network Devices

Monitoring_Servers   Monitoring Servers

Juice_-_Tomato       Juice - Tomato

Hello_World          Hello World

File_Server          File Server
```

First I get the directory config "Linux" for the tool 1

```
path = '*/some_place/app1' 
for directory1 in os.listdir(path):  #<type 'str'>
```

After I get the settings from tool 2 via a REST request

```
# 
 ... urllib2 library
#     
app2conf = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(request).read()  #<type 'dict'>
```

Now i´m ready to perform the syn, if a directory in the tool 1 exist in the tool 2, print "exist" else print "Do you want to create?" my script is like this:

```
def sync(directory1, app2conf):    
    for dirin2 in app2conf:                            #<type 'unicode'>
        if directory1 == str(dirin2.replace(" ", "_")):
            print 'Directory already exist'
            return str(dirin2)                         #unicode to string
        else:
            print 'Do you want to create?'
            #
             some code to create directories
            #

for directory1 in os.listdir(path):
    getsync = sync(directory1,app2conf)
    print getsync 
    #
     More code 
    #
```

The problem is the return gets me None valúes in "print getsync".

```
Network Devices
Monitoring Servers
None                   #<type 'NoneType'>
Juice - Tomato
Hello World
File Server
```

For measurements i'm print al 2 values after if

```
def sync(directory1, app2conf):    
        for dirin2 in app2conf:        #<type 'unicode'>
            if directory1 == str(dirin2.replace(" ", "_")):
                print directory1
                print dirin2
```

And i get somenting like this

```
Network_Devices
Network Devices
Monitoring_Servers
Monitoring Servers
Juice_-_Tomato
Juice - Tomato
Hello_World
Hello World
File_Server
File Server
```

The script is working, but i don't know why the return gives me these values.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Your `sync` procedure may not be returning anything, specifically your `else` clause doesn't appear to have a `return` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of data you're using, but "unicode to string" may not be such a good idea. Why make that conversion?

Comment: The api to get the data from the app 2 returns "unicode" values. I need the "getsync" to perform more operations in the script: modify, delete, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the string for the item you created in the else clause. Otherwise the sync function will only return None (the default for python functions) and you will get None assigned to getsync.

Comment: I understand my mistake. will try with some exceptions, Thanks.